# v-if is not updated when importing a 3rd party script with vue-meta

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I want to use vue-meta to import a 3rd party SwiperJS script into my nuxt website.

The script is loaded only after `mounted()`-hook is called so I also initialize it on `update()`. This kind of works but the `v-if` on the wrapper does not update.

```vue
<template>
  <section
    class="swiper"
    v-if="isSwiperLoaded"
  >
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> ... </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { swiperLoaded: false, swiperInitialized: false }
  },
  computed: {
    isSwiperLoaded: {
      get() {
        return this.swiperLoaded
      },
      set(value) {
        this.swiperLoaded = value
      },
    },
    isSwiperInitialized: {
      get() {
        return this.swiperInitialized
      },
      set(value) {
        this.swiperInitialized = value
      },
    },
  },
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          hid: 'swiper',
          src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js',
          defer: true,
          // Changed after script load
          callback: () => {
            this.isSwiperLoaded = true
          },
        },
      ],
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          type: 'text/css',
          href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initSwiper() {
      const swiperOptions = {
        ...
      }

      let swiper = new Swiper(this.$el, swiperOptions)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.isSwiperInitialized && this.isSwiperLoaded) {
      console.log('INIT LOADED')
      this.initSwiper()
      this.isSwiperInitialized = true
    }
  },
  updated() {
    if (!this.isSwiperInitialized && this.isSwiperLoaded) {
      console.log('UPD LOADED')
      this.initSwiper()
      this.isSwiperInitialized = true
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Also I noticed the `computed` values are normally for getting and setting values from store and not local values. Maybe there is an easier way of updating the variables.

Comment: First off, why are you even loading them as CDNs? Use NPM and install the packages locally. You will get less headache and better performance.

Comment: Otherwise, you can check my profile. I've already answered some questions regarding 3rd party scripts.

Comment: @kissu I normally load scripts as CDN, so users who have them in cache do not have to load them again (performance gain). Or isn't this the way to go anymore?

Comment: Hm, I guess this is cachable indeed. Meanwhile, you need to fetch it at least once before it's cached hence why the initial fetch will be slower. Still, you may need to fetch it, the CDN may be down, slow to respond. While if you build it, you already have it in your app, and it will be more optimized overall, easier to use, easier to track and to upgrade. Some packages are not even supported as ESM imports too. So no, there is really not a lot of reasons to use a CDN behind a "gonna drop that link there for quick prototyping" but it's usually harder to pull than an NPM install at the end.